# How can I subtract a value of one object array from another object array

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and I want to deduct Quantity in `openOrders` from Stock in `cybertill`, where SKU matches to `Ref`

```
cybertill = [
{
    Ref: 'BLD188',
    Stock: '4',
  },
  {
    Ref: 'BEX1403',
    Stock: '7',
  }
];

openOrders = [
{
    SKU: 'BLD188',
    Quantity: '1',
  },
  {
    SKU: 'BEX1403',
    Quantity: '2',
  }
];
```

Im trying to get one object array that has the difference between the Stock and the Quantity, `t`

```
stockLeft = [
{
    Ref: 'BLD188',
    Stock: '3', //Which is 4 - 1
  },
  {
    Ref: 'BEX1403',
    Stock: '5', //Which is 7 -2
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over the `cybertill` array, where `map` will construct a new **array** based on the logic you need.

The logic you have is to calculate the difference, based on the `Ref` and the `SKU` attributes, between the `Stock` values you have in the `cybertill` array and the `Quantity` values found in the `openOrders` array.

To do so, we may pass a function to the `map` method, that iterates over the `cybertill` array, that, at each iteration, constructs an object that will have the `Ref` and the difference we calculated (saved in the `Stock` attribute of that new object).

So to illustrate, here's a live demo describing the above logic:

```js
const cybertill = [{
      Ref: 'BLD188',
      Stock: '4',
    },
    {
      Ref: 'BEX1403',
      Stock: '7',
    }
  ],
  openOrders = [{
      SKU: 'BLD188',
      Quantity: '1',
    },
    {
      SKU: 'BEX1403',
      Quantity: '2',
    }
  ],
  /** map (loop) over "cybertill" and construct an array containing the desired diff values */
  stockLeft = cybertill.map(o => {
    /** 
     * o: holds an object from "cybertill" at each iteration.
     * d: the object that will hold the difference of the current iteration.
     * order: holds the object that has the same "Ref" in the "open,Orders" array.
     */
    const d = o,
      order = openOrders.find(oo => oo.SKU == o.Ref);

    /**
     * if we have found an entry in "openOrders" that matches the current "Ref" (o.Ref) then we do the substraction.
     * otherwise the diff object will be the same as the "o" (the current iteration's object from "cybertill" array).
     */
    order && (d['Stock'] -= order.Quantity);

    /** retrun the constructed order that will likely to have the diff we want */
    return d;
  });

/** print the result */
console.log(stockLeft);
```

In the above demo, the array `stockLeft` should be equal to:

```js
[
  {
    "Ref": "BLD188",
    "Stock": 3
  },
  {
    "Ref": "BEX1403",
    "Stock": 5
  }
]
```